# How do I merge a tuple or convert a list to a tuple?

Tags: python, django, merge, append

I have a tuple, INSTALLED_APPS, and I want to merge extra items into it to get my local apps in the tuple too without altering the main settings file. I came this far:

```
DEFAULT_APPS = list(INSTALLED_APPS)
MY_APPS_LIST = DEFAULT_APPS.append('south')
```

however if I try to convert this into a tuple again by running:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = tuple(MY_APPS_LIST)
```

I get:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

The question is rather fundamental I'd say, but I can't really find "the" method for this, or even any method that works for me at all... I did find that both list() and tuple() in the Django shell return an empty object of that type, so I don't understand where the TypeError might be coming from...

Help appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for all the correct answers!Isbadawi was first so I'll accept his answer, but thanks to all, for the background info too!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`append` doesn't return a new list -- it modifies the original list, returning `None`. You want `MY_APPS_LIST = DEFAULT_APPS + ['south']`

Answer (score 3):

`list` methods operate in-place, and hence return `None`. If you want to add another element to an existing list and only return the result then just add them.

```
MY_APPS_LIST = DEFAULT_APPS + ['south']
```

Answer (score 3):

note that one can use `+` to concatenate tuples, so if `INSTALLED_APPS` is a tuple:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = DEFAULT_APPS + ('south',)
```

`INSTALLED_APPS` will be a tuple with `'south'` as its last element

Answer (score 1):

The `list.append` method does NOT return the list you appended to. It is an in-place method. You should be doing

```
DEFAULT_APPS = list(INSTALLED_APPS)
DEFAULT_APPS.append('south')
MY_APPS_LIST = DEFAULT_APPS
```

Comment: This also adds 'south' to DEFAULT_APPS. It's not clear from the question whether this is desirable.

Comment: It doesn't matter. The answer is as correct as all the others where. Thanks.